# Delete the duplicate words from array of strings in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with 2 varchar columns - col_name1 and col_name2

```
(1, 'hello world', 'hello test'),
(2, 'the stack over', 'over the flow'),
(3, 'hello from my sql fiddle', 'hello my sql');
```

See SQLFIDDLE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf90c1/1

I'm looking for a way to find the duplicate words in two columns and DELETE such the words from col_name1.

It means after a Mysql operation + UPDATE + SET - col_name1 should contain the words like below

```
(1, 'world', 'hello test'),
(2, 'stack', 'over the flow'),
(3, 'from fiddle', 'hello my sql');
```

Comment: Fix your data model!  Storing multiple values in a single column is not the best approach.  You should be using junction/association tables.

Comment: To do this with your data as is, you would need some kind of grep/regex support, neither of which MySQL supports.

Comment: So what I understand, first you want to identify the duplicate words out of both varchar column, then you want to delete the duplicated value from first varchar column, is it?

Comment: @KKK exactly right !

Comment: I think you will need to write a function, that takes two strings iterates over every word in the one string and removes all occurrences of that word in the other, finally returning the other, manipulated string. I don't think it's feasible with anything MySQL provides out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem:

The SQL that resolve your problem statement:

```
update table_name x3
join (
select id,replace(group_concat(w),',',' ') w from (SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.c, ' ', x.x), ' ', -1) w
FROM (SELECT id,concat(col_name1) c FROM table_name) t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 + a.i + b.i * 10 x
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b
) x
ON (LENGTH(t.c) +1 - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.c, ' ', ''))) >= x.x
group by id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.c, ' ', x.x), ' ', -1)) x2
where not exists (select 1 from (SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.c, ' ', x.x), ' ', -1) w
FROM (SELECT id,concat(col_name2,' ',col_name1) c FROM table_name) t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 + a.i + b.i * 10 x
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b
) x
ON (LENGTH(t.c) +1 - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.c, ' ', ''))) >= x.x
group by id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.c, ' ', x.x), ' ', -1) 
having count(1) > 1) x1 where x2.id = x1.id and x2.w = x1.w)
group by id
) x
on x3.id = x.id
set x3.col_name1 = x.w;
```

## Below is the Example from sample data to expected output:

```
mysql> create table table_name(id int, col_name1 varchar(200),col_name2 varchar(200));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.36 sec)

mysql> insert into table_name values
    -> (1, 'hello world', 'hello test'),
    -> (2, 'the stack over', 'over the flow'),
    -> (3, 'hello from my sql fiddle', 'hello my sql');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.11 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> update table_name x3
    -> join (
    -> select id,replace(group_concat(w),',',' ') w from (SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.c, ' ', x.x), ' ', -1) w
    -> FROM (SELECT id,concat(col_name1) c FROM table_name) t
    -> INNER JOIN
    -> (
    ->     SELECT 1 + a.i + b.i * 10 x
    ->     FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a
    ->     CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b
    -> ) x
    -> ON (LENGTH(t.c) +1 - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.c, ' ', ''))) >= x.x
    -> group by id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.c, ' ', x.x), ' ', -1)) x2
    -> where not exists (select 1 from (SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.c, ' ', x.x), ' ', -1) w
    -> FROM (SELECT id,concat(col_name2,' ',col_name1) c FROM table_name) t
    -> INNER JOIN
    -> (
    ->     SELECT 1 + a.i + b.i * 10 x
    ->     FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a
    ->     CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b
    -> ) x
    -> ON (LENGTH(t.c) +1 - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.c, ' ', ''))) >= x.x
    -> group by id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.c, ' ', x.x), ' ', -1) 
    -> having count(1) > 1) x1 where x2.id = x1.id and x2.w = x1.w)
    -> group by id
    -> ) x
    -> on x3.id = x.id
    -> set x3.col_name1 = x.w;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.13 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from table_name;
+------+-------------+---------------+
| id   | col_name1   | col_name2     |
+------+-------------+---------------+
|    1 | world       | hello test    |
|    2 | stack       | over the flow |
|    3 | from fiddle | hello my sql  |
+------+-------------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hope, It will resolve your problem.
All the best!!!

## EDIT - as per request of question owner: To handle a large amount of words. Now It will handle the words upto 10000

```
update table_name x3
join (
select id,replace(group_concat(w),',',' ') w from (SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.c, ' ', x.x), ' ', -1) w
FROM (SELECT id,concat(col_name1) c FROM table_name) t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 + a.i + b.i * 10 x
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) d 
) x
ON (LENGTH(t.c) +1 - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.c, ' ', ''))) >= x.x
group by id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.c, ' ', x.x), ' ', -1)) x2
where not exists (select 1 from (SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.c, ' ', x.x), ' ', -1) w
FROM (SELECT id,concat(col_name2,' ',col_name1) c FROM table_name) t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 + a.i + b.i * 10 x
    FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) d 
) x
ON (LENGTH(t.c) +1 - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.c, ' ', ''))) >= x.x
group by id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.c, ' ', x.x), ' ', -1) 
having count(1) > 1) x1 where x2.id = x1.id and x2.w = x1.w)
group by id
) x
on x3.id = x.id
set x3.col_name1 = x.w;
```

Comment: when I test your scripts it seems to me I try a magic ! This is even not a complex MySQL query, this is something beyond my understanding :) It's even not fair to give only 1 star at Stack.
And YES, it works !

Comment: I make various real tests - could you tell me what factor to increase if try this script on bigger volumes ? Let's say varchar 5000 ?

Comment: In SQL there is two time I used the below code: From below code:
 (
     SELECT 1 + a.i + b.i * 10 x
     FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b
) x

Comment: Just copy and paste : below line so the string value will be multiplied with 10:       CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b

Comment: So, you have to copy the statement with "CROSS JOIN" till ending at "b" i.e. one line from SQL and paste it twice and give name as "c" and "d" for both of places.

Comment: Let me know if any issue

Comment: I'm testing but without a success while...could you update your answer with your fixes for big volumes ? I'd like to copy the code entirely again to avoid the misunderstandings...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171644/discussion-between-kkk-and-serge).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8.0, you can use a recursive Common Table Expressions (CTE) to iterate over the string to find all words.  The following UPDATE statement should do the work:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
word_boundaries (id, i, start, stop) AS (
  SELECT id, 1, 1, LOCATE(' ', col_name1, 1) FROM table_name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, i+1, stop+1, LOCATE(' ', col_name1, stop+1)
  FROM word_boundaries JOIN table_name USING(id) WHERE stop != 0
),
words(id, i, word) AS (
  SELECT id, i, IF(stop != 0,
                   SUBSTRING(col_name1, start, stop-start),
                   SUBSTRING(col_name1, start))
  FROM table_name JOIN word_boundaries USING(id)
),
unique_words(id, i, word) AS (
  SELECT id, i, word FROM words JOIN table_name USING(id)
  WHERE LOCATE(word, col_name2) = 0
),
new_text(id, new_colname1) AS (
  SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(word ORDER BY i SEPARATOR ' ')
  FROM unique_words
  GROUP BY id
)
UPDATE table_name
SET col_name1 = 
    (SELECT new_colname1 FROM new_text WHERE id = table_name.id);
```

This UPDATE statement uses multiple CTEs:

- word_boundaries: Identifies start and stop position of each word
- words: All words in col_name1
- unique_words: All words not present in corresponding col_name2
- new_text: Generates the new column value by concatenating all words from unique_words for each row id

If your strings may contain more than 1000 space characters, you will have to increase the value of cte_max_recursion_depth.  Defining table_name.id as a PRIMARY KEY should speed up things when table is large.

I think this example shows how useful CTEs are in breaking down a complex task into simpler steps.